# Keeping users logged in

Tags: php, cookies, authentication

I want to keep users logged in my site until they logout(clear cookies).It works until they close browsers.Is there a good way to store cookies when we close browsers.

Comment: A cookie lives for as long as you tell it to; they contain an expiry date.  A date in the future will allow the cookie to remain between restarts for as long as specified ...

Comment: i know but how? i asked this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Cookie` in php has feature to set `time`

so you can specify time for it

```
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30)); // whatever time you need ,864000 = 1day
```

Comment: after I set it how can I get it. Actually how can I use it. Like checking is user logged in? And thanks for your answer!.

Comment: @MervliTürkmen simply echo $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `$_COOKIE` and `functions` such as `setCookie()`
More help: http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
setcookie($cookie_name, $val, time()-3600);
```

i hope it will be helpful.